# Going offline with angular application

Tags: angularjs, offline

I am working on a angular project that requires some offline capability, i have researched online but no making much progress. I have tried the angular interceptor to hijack the http.get request when offline and give a success response (by using the data stored in localstorage). Can anyone point me to some help?

Comment: If your application has a database and you love yourself I recommend not doing this